# new int[ix];で動的確保した配列の要素数を獲得する方法

Tags: c++

配列の要素数を得る方法なのですが`int z[50];`の場合は以下の例で50と変数に入るのですが。
なぜポインターにnew intしてから要素数を得ようとすると1と表示されるのでしょうか？
また、どうしたら要素数を得られるのか教えてくれますでしょうか？

```
int main() {

    int *x;
    x = new int[50];    
    int z[50];

    int a = sizeof(z) / sizeof(z[0]);
    int b = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;



    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問１の答：
`sizeof (x)` はポインタの大きさを得ます (32bit ならたいてい 4)
`sizeof(x[0])` は `int` の大きさを得ます (32bit ならたいてい 4)
なので `4/4==1` を得るだけのことです。 64bit Windows 用コンパイラなら別の値を得るでしょう。

質問２の答：
どの処理系でも通用する方法はただ一つ、自分で覚えておくことです。

```
struct myvector {
    int* p; // new int [size] の結果
    int size; // 事前に new したい数を記憶しておく
};
```

これを自分で行うのはあまりにも馬鹿らしいので `std::vector` を使うとよいでしょう。 `vector` は端的には `new T[capacity]` のラッパ (Wrapper) です。必要な時に自動で `delete[]` してくれて便利便利。
- `vector.capacity` は `new T[capacity]` したってこと
- `vector.size` はそのうち、ユーザーが「使っている」と宣言した個数
要素を１００個用意しても `vector.reserve(100)`  、３０個しか使っていない `vector.size()==30`ってのはよくある話。このとき残り７０個はリロケーションなしに `vector.push_back` できる。

Comment: この解説には説明を簡単にするための誤りが故意に含まれていますので、全部鵜呑みにしないでください。どこがどう誤っているのかわかるようになれば `vector` について深く理解できているということでお願いしたいです。